# No extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#

I have a very simple method like this:-

```
public async Task<XrmActivity> GetById(Guid id)
{
   return await this.GetById<XrmActivity>(id, "activityid", fetchXml);
}
```

But I get the following error:-

> 'XrmActivity' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'XrmActivity' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is going on ? Please help. I have found other Links in Stack Overflow and I wasn't very sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

> What is going on?

`this.GetById<XrmActivity>(id, "activityid", fetchXml)` is returning `XrmActivity`, which is not an awaitable type. Thus, you cannot use it with `await`.

To resolve, either:

- Change `GetById(Guid, string, typeof(fetchXml))` to return a `Task<XrmActivity>` instead of an `XrmActivity`, or:
- Change `GetById(Guid)` to be synchronous, i.e., `public XrmActivity GetById(Guid id) => GetById<XrmActivity>(id, "activityid", fetchXml);`

Answer (score -1):

I am new to C# so I can not explain why this might work, but it worked for me. I did find this method in a online tutorial. Try `return await Task.Run(() => this.GetById<XrmActivity>(id, "activityid", fetchXml));`

I suppose this is a way of asynchronously calling synchronous methods

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.